# MSBuild and Packages with Content Files

Tags: c#, package, msbuild, nuget, msbuild-4.0

I have a problem with MSBuild an packages.

I have an application referencing an package which references a package, which has **contentFiles** in it like:

**Main App A -> Assembly B -> Package C** with assemblies and content files (exe + json)!

These content files are executables who are needed by the main application to run (remote api with pipes / proxy).

Problem: these exe-content files included in the **Package C** referenced by **Assembly B** are **NOT** written to the output folder of **Main App A**! They are only written to the output folder of **Assembly B**.

Is there a way to solve my problem **without** using a copy command or **Main App A** referencing **Package C**?

**Package C** content:

[image]

Regards

Comment: Project A has a `ProjectReference` to Project B and Project B has a `PackageReference` to C? If that is the case, then in Project A try setting the [`RestoreProjectStyle` property to `PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#using-packagereference-for-a-project-with-no-package-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem by embedding the executables of Package C in Assembly B and dumping the executables at runtime into the entry assemblies folder.**